# bottle.py on EC2 micro instance causes 2 order of magnitude slowdown

Tags: amazon-ec2, python, web-applications, amazon-web-services

Cross-posted from [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4487820/bottle-py-on-ec2-micro-instance-causes-2-order-of-magnitude-slowdown):

I wrote a little toy script to solve [this](http://www.playfish.com/?page=game_wordchallenge) type of game, and put it on my new micro EC2 instance. [It](http://pastebin.ca/2024254) works perfectly, but while it takes around 0.5 seconds to run a [local](http://pastebin.ca/2024255) version, and takes under 0.5 seconds to run both the local and the bottle.py version on my home computer, running the bottle.py version on the EC2 instance takes over 2 minutes.

Python has the cpu pegged at 99% the entire time.  Only 7.4% memory usage, consistently, and no swapping.  The only guess I have is initialization time for bottle.py on EC2, but if it were that, why would it be ~200x faster on my own computer with bottle.py?

Comment: Out of curiosity, which `pybloomfilter` are you using? I'm getting "TypeError: too many initializers" on the `scrambled =` line. Or is there something else that's causing that error?

Comment: Instead of pybloom, I went with [pybloomfiltermmap](http://github.com/axiak/pybloomfiltermmap) from [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/311202/modern-high-performance-bloom-filter-in-python). It works fantastically well in every use case except when called by bottle.py on EC2.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon micro instances only guarantee a small amount of CPU, but will occasionally burst additional CPU resources.  If you have a CPU intensive script, it will run slowly on a micro instance most of the time by design.  More information is in the Amazon announcement here:

http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2010/09/09/announcing-micro-instances-for-amazon-ec2/